# How do I terminate a .NET thread that has had its call stack corrupted?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread in my application that is running code that can potentially cause call stack corruption ( my application is a testing tool for dlls ).

Assuming that I have a method of detecting if the child thread is misbehaving, how would I terminate it? From what I read, calling Thread.Abort() on the misbehaving thread would be equivalent to raising an exception inside it.I fear that that not be a good idea, provided the call stack of the thread might be corrupted.Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to rewrite the code because that should never happen.

Comment: As I said, I am trying to make a testing tool, so I must assume that any dll function i'm testing is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Once again my reading comprehension has failed me. My apologies.

Comment: This article might interest you, it is from Eric Lippert himself: [Careful with that axe, should I specify timeout?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx)

Comment: If we could read normal languages, why would we be in computer science ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running untrusted code that could corrupt your process run that code in a separate process and communicate with it using interprocess communication. If you want to terminate the untrusted code early, you can just kill the process.

Comment: Suddenly I have that Monzy song "Kill dash nine" stuck in my head.

Answer (score 3):

If code is misbehaving, it can do *anything*, and it can affect anything in the entire process, on any thread.

The most reliable solution is to run the untrusted code in a separate process, then terminate the process if it misbehaves.

Comment: killing always do. Running it on Your own thread would be just risky, and unreliable, thanks to possible untrusted finalizers which can do plainly ANYTHING...

Answer (score 3):

Load the DLL into a new AppDomain and run the code in the DLL from there using the [AppDomain.DoCallBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accept answer, I'd like to add that it is trivially easy to ignore Thread.Abort.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
   Thread.ResetAbort();
}
```